# Laravel select db raw groupBy

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-query-builder

I would like to display this query in laravel :

```
SELECT products.*, (

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM category
WHERE category.product_id = products.id
AND category.date_creation BETWEEN '2018-02-16 00:00:00' AND '2018-02-19 23:59:59' 
GROUP BY product_id
)nbr
FROM products
```

i try with this :

```
    $a= $date_du;
    $b = $date_au;
    $products = DB::table('products')                                    
    ->leftjoin('category','category.product_id','=','products.id')
    ->select('products.*',
       DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM category 
       WHERE category.product_id = products.id AND category.date_creation >= '$a' AND category.date_creation <= '$b' group by product_id) as nbr"))                                     
    ->get();
```

But clause **group by** doesn't work.

Comment: Why are you not using Rships?

Comment: Is the sql query you provided works correctly ?

Comment: I've added my answer. Have a try. If you provide your problem in more detail it would be quite easier to give better answer.

Comment: @SagarGautam, your answer it works very well

Comment: I feel good it helped you. Congrats :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one,

```
$products = DB::table('products')
            ->leftjoin('category','category.product_id','=','products.id')
            ->whereBetween('date_creation',[$a,$b])
            ->select(DB::raw('COUNT(*) as nbr'), 'products.*')
            ->groupBy('id')
            ->get();
```

This might work for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this :

```
$products=DB::select("SELECT products.*, ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM category WHERE category.product_id = products.id AND category.date_creation BETWEEN '2018-02-16 00:00:00' AND '2018-02-19 23:59:59' GROUP BY product_id )nbr FROM products" );
```

This will run a raw query and will return the desired output.